# Objective-C SCNetworkReachabilityContext ARC conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

While converting an app to use Automatic Reference Counting I came across this error:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

*Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC*

This fixes the compiler error, but gives a warning:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, objc_unretainedPointer(self), NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

How to get rid of this warning?

*Initializing 'void *' with an expression of type 'objc_objectptr_t' (aka 'const void *') discards qualifiers*

Comment: Have you tried just casting it to void*? I'm not sure if that's the correct solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to cast self (id) to a void * without problem.

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, ( void * )self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked with a bridged cast. (__bridge void *)self

Comment: this isn't a bridged call, (void*)objc_unretainedPointer(self) would be the more accurate way to go here.

Comment: Someone ARCified Apple's reachability example here. https://gist.github.com/1182373