# Bridging and ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting some code over to ARC and  per the compiler  error message, I need to bridge this code:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

I looked at the docs and yet something is not correct. Can someone tell me why this bridge cast is not working? Thanks

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, (__bridge_retained SCNetworkReachabilityContext)self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151362/objective-c-scnetworkreachabilitycontext-arc-conversion

Comment: Paul, that  certainly helped. Thanks. The actual solution was to do this:     SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, (__bridge_retained  void * )self, NULL, NULL, NULL};

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul Hunter's link reference above, I was able to get closer to figuring this out. The actual solution was to do this:

```
SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, (__bridge_retained void * )self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```